# Update only new data from Firebase in SwiftUI

Tags: firebase, swiftui, userdefaults

My question is very complex, and my English is not that well, so please excuse if you don't understand me.

I have a SwiftUI File, which builds for each Item in a folder on my firebase an special Button.

If I touch this Button, it will hide. The problem is, I want that if the SwiftUI File reloads, I want to see only these Buttons which I haven't tapped before. (I want to Store which Buttons are Tapped). The Problem is, each time I reload the SwiftUI File, It'll make new Buttons, which aren't tapped yet.

My Question is now, how can I create only for the new Items in my Folder (on the firebase) an Button. The old once should be displayed too, if they were not tapped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store Bool in Firebase. Just load items which false and when you tap a button you make the value true.

Comment: Good Idea, But this don‘t work because if you log In with an other account, it should Mark everything as new.

Comment: So get document id from item, when an user tap button to hide, you can save true for this user in backend. It will hide only who tap the button, for another users it will mark as new.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say, not all of the Users are logged in

Comment: Are you using Firebase Authentication?

Comment: yes I am, but not each user has to log in to use the app

Comment: You can let users log in with authenticaton but without password, email or phone number. Then use their auth id and save in server.